# String to DateTime C#

Tags: c#

Здрасвуйте, пишу бота на VK API который выдает аккаунты, и мне нужно записывать в какое время он выдал аккаунт, записывает он в формате G

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("G")); //запись идет в файл но тут изображу как вывод на консоль
```

И мне нужно из 01.01.2000 12:12:12 получить DateTime для дальнейшей обработки.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()`, не?

Comment: Ну, чтобы не изобретать костылей, надо изучать стандартную библиотеку. Рекомендую почитать труд Албахари

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` — то, что надо. Но не забудьте указать локаль:

```
var s = "01.01.2000 12:12:12";
var rusCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, rusCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dt))
    Console.WriteLine(dt); // <-- выполняется эта строка
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not recognized");
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @pavel1787mego: Смотрите. Дата в каждом из языков записывается по-разному. Код указывает функции `DateTime.TryParse`, что нужно строку интерпретировать как строку в русском формате. Например, в американском формате сначала пишется месяц, а потом день, а у нас наоборот.

Comment: @pavel1787mego: Пожалуйста!